# Javascript: Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length) not producing a random number?

Tags: javascript, random, while-loop, infinite-loop

This on e is a doozey.

I have while loop to generate a random number that is not the same as any other random number produced before. The random number is used to select a text value from an object.

for example:

```
quoteArray[1] = "some text"
quoteArray[2] = "some different text"
quoteArray[3] = "text again"
quoteArray[4] = "completely different text"
quoteArray[5] = "ham sandwich"
```

This is part of a larger function and after that function has cycled through = quoteArray.length it resets and starts the cycle over again. The issue I am hitting is that the following code is SOMETIMES producing an infinite loop:

```
//Note: at this point in the function I have generated a random number once already and stored it in 'randomnumber'
//I use this while statement to evaluate 'randomnumber' until the condition of it NOT being a number that has already been used and NOT being the last number is met.
while(randomnumber === rotationArray[randomnumber] || randomnumber === lastnumber){
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quoteArray.length));
}
```

When I console.log(randomnumber) - when I am stuck in the loop - I am just getting '0' as a result. When stuck in the loop it doesn't appear as though Math.floor(Math.random() * (quoteArray.length)) is producing a random number but rather just '0' infinitely.

can anyone tell me why I am running into  this problem?

**EDIT: Here is the complete pertinent code with function + variable declarations**

```
// Function to initialize the quoteObj
    function quoteObj(text,cname,ccompany,url,height) {
            this.text=text;
            this.cname=cname;
            this.ccompany=ccompany;
            this.url=url;
            this.height=height;
        }

// Populate my quotes Object with the quotation information from the XML sheet. 

    var qObj = new quoteObj('','','','');
    var quoteArray = new Array();
    var counter = 0;

//cycles through each XML item and loads the data into an object which is then stored in an array
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "quotes.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('quote').each(function(){
                quoteArray[counter] = new quoteObj('','','','');
                console.log(quoteArray[counter]);
                quoteArray[counter].text = $(this).find('text').text();
                quoteArray[counter].cname = $(this).find('customer_name').text();
                quoteArray[counter].ccompany = $(this).find('customer_company').text();
                quoteArray[counter].url = $(this).find('project').text();
                ++counter;
            });
        }
    });

// This is the setion that is generating my infinite loop issue.
// I've included all of the other code in case people are wondering specific things about how an item was initialized, etc. 

// Generate a random first quote then randomly progress through the entire set and start all over.      

    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quoteArray.length));
    var rotationArray = new Array(quoteArray.length);
    var v = 0;
    var lastnumber = -1;

    bHeight = $('#rightbox').height() + 50;
    var cHeight = 0;
    var divtoanim = $('#customerquotes').parent();

//NOT RELATED// 
// Give the innershadow a height so that overflow hidden works with the quotations. 
    $(divtoanim).css({'height' : bHeight});

// Rotate the Quotations Randomly function. 
    setInterval(function(){     
        randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quoteArray.length));

//checks to see if the function loop needs to start at the beginning. 
        if(v == (quoteArray.length)){
            rotationArray.length = 0;
            v = 0;
        }
//determines if the random number is both different than any other random number generated before and that is is not the same as the last random number
        while(randomnumber === rotationArray[randomnumber] || randomnumber === lastnumber){
            randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quoteArray.length));
        }   

        lastnumber = randomnumber;
        rotationArray[randomnumber] = randomnumber;
        ++v;

//NOT RELATED//
//animation sequence
        $('#ctext, #cname').animate({'opacity':'0'},2000, function(){
            $('#ctext').html(quoteArray[randomnumber].text);
            $('#cname').html('- ' + quoteArray[randomnumber].cname);

            cHeight = $('#customerquotes').height() + 50;
            adjustHeight(bHeight,cHeight,divtoanim);

            $('#ctext').delay(500).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
            $('#cname').delay(1500).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
        });
    },15000);
```

Comment: What is `rotationArray` and how do you reset the cycle?

Comment: How exactly are you **declaring** this array?

Comment: To cut to it, if "quoteArray" is not defined with `var quoteArray = [];` or `var quoteArray = new Array();` then it may not really be an array at all.

Comment: rotationArray is an array that stores the random number generated for each cycle.

Comment: quoteArray is declared like this: var quoteArray = new Array();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an asynchronous problem: the array `quoteArray` is empty when the code runs, because it fires off the ajax request, *and moves on*. Anything that depends on `quoteArray` should be inside the `success` function of `$.ajax`.

The array has a length when you type `quoteArray.length` in the console, **only because** by that time the Ajax request has completed.

Comment: I'm not writing "console.log(randomnumber) in firebug, i just wrote it inline in the code so every time it iterates through the while loop i was getting readout of what 'randomnumber' was.

Comment: @user yes, even with that. Setting `async: false` will cause the browser to block everything else, but the script after the `$.ajax` will still run. `async: false` is usually *not* what you're looking for.

Comment: @user, and if you put `console.log(quoteArray.length);` in the **same** loop, you should get `0`.

Comment: @box9 Thank you for the clarification! I was under the wrong impression. I guess the other thing is that a) this function does not run until 15 seconds after the page has loaded and b) looking at ajax requests through firebug they are all complete before this runs so while i understand your answer i dont understand how it applies in this situation.

Comment: also noteworthy: If i didn't make it clear in the beginning, this script does run successfully sometimes(in Chrome, Firefox and IE). I seem to have the problem with the infinite loop only in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome.

Comment: would a link to the page be more helpful?

Comment: disclaimer: this infinite loop will cause your browser to lock up! http://www.bonpixel.com/NotReleased/index.html

Comment: @Priv the infinite loop happened once for me, but then I couldn't reproduce it after that... it seems to work now!

Comment: Shoot! I hate intermittent problems!!! arg!! Try opening multiple instances of the page, like 3 or 4.

Comment: I am able to recreate the situation consistently by launching two instances of the index.html simultaneously. The best approach I've found is to open 2 instances then close FF and save the session. Then open FF again and the window that is not in the foreground will have the loop failure. I built in an alert that counts the number of 0's produced from the while loop and alerts at 100 which temporarily 'breaks' the script but after hitting ok it will continue to loop

Comment: I added a conditional statement to stop the function if the quoteArray.length is <= 1. This basically makes the quotation static on the page that has the unpopulated quoteArray. I'm still confused as to why the ajax request does not complete on the page that is in the background? but this seems to be the closest to an answer although I don't think it completely addresses the issue. Thank you all for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (5));
```

To make sure the array length is being found properly?

Comment: I am sure that the array length is being found properly because I also used console.log(quoteArray.length) which is returning a number greater than 0. quoteArray.length is going to depend on the number of times the function has cycled through.

Answer (score 0):

First, since you updated your question, be sure that you are handling asynchronous data properly. Since an ajax call is asynchronous, you will need to be sure to only run the randomizer once the call is successful and data has been returned.

Second, assuming you are handling the asyc data properly, the size of your result set is likely it is too small. Thus, you are probably randomly getting the same number too often. Then, you can't use this number because you have already done so.

What you need to do is pop off the parts that are already used from the results array each time. Recalculate the array length, then pull a random from that. However, the likelihood of this feeling random is very slim.

There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but here's my go:

```
var results = ['some text','some text2','some text3','some text4','some text5', /* ...etc */ ],
       randomable = results;

function getRandomOffset( arr )
{
    var offset,
           len;

    if( arr.length < 1 )
        return false;
    else if( arr.length > 1 )
        offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length );
    else
        offset = 0;

    arr.splice( offset, 1 );

    return [
        offset,
        arr
    ];

}

while( res = getRandomOffset( randomable ) )
{
    // Set the randomable for next time
    randomable = res[1];
    // Do something with your resulting index
    results[ res[0] ];
}
```

The `arr`gument sent to the function should be the array that is returned form it (except the first time). Then call that function as you need until it returns false.